# Problem to start Myst IV on Mac OS 10.6

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard

And thanks for your instructions to install Myst IV on Mac OS 10.6.
I follow all steps, the installation was successful, but I can't start the game. I have always the same message "Myst4 a quitté de manière imprévue" (sorry in french I'm french...).

Could you see what the problem ?
Thanks.

Create a folder on your desktop called myst4
Inside this folder make two more folders, one called Myst4_1 and one called Myst4_2
Insert disk 1 and open the terminal
Type cd /Volumes/Myst4_1
Type cp -Rv * ~/Desktop/myst4/Myst4_1 - this will take a while
Type cd /
Eject disk 1 and insert disk 2
Type cd /Volumes/Myst4_2
Type cp -Rv * ~/Desktop/myst4/Myst4_2 - this will take a while
Type cd ~/Desktop/myst4/Myst4_1
Type unzip Macinstaller.jar
Type java run - The installer will load
Accept all the defaults, keep clicking next
When prompted for disk 2, navigate to Desktop/myst4/Myst4_2 and click open
The application is now installed. Not to run the game.

At the terminal 1. Type cd /Ubisoft/MystIV 2. Type chmod -R 777 myst4.app

Run the game by opening Myst4 under the Macintosh HD/Ubisoft/MystIV directory.

Comment: If you could translate that into English that would help...

Comment: Not knowing anything about French, I would say "Myst4 has quit in a manner unexpected" roughly translates to "Myst4 has unexpectedly quit."